# Using FirstOrDefault vs From

Tags: c#, linq

I have been using Linq methods for a while in my project. But got to know an another way of writing them.

What I wrote:

```
dbContext.Currencies
         .FirstOrDefault(cr => cr.Name.EqualInvariant(currencyName))
```

Another way I got to know:

```
(from curr in dbContext.Currencies 
 where curr.Name == currencyName select curr).FirstOrDefault();
```

Which method is more efficient?

Comment: Please check this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/query-syntax-and-method-syntax-in-linq

Comment: They do exactly the same, just alternative syntax. So.. equally efficient.

Comment: No difference, the two line will generate the same query, it's a personal preference to use one of these styles ... personally I prefer the first one (LINQ) because it more compact and readable

Comment: If we are talking about LINQ to Objects, first one is more effective, because there is additional `Where` in second query. For LINQ to Entities (EF, Linq To Sql, NHibernate, linq2db, etc.) both queries are identical.